# second remote git repo with submodules

Tags: git

I am working with a git repository that contains a few submodules. In fact most of the work happens in the submodules and the root repo is just a way to keep things together.

What I would like to do is to copy the root (and all its folders) into another repository.

In the end, I would like to be able to push and pull from multiple remotes where one of the remote maintains the submodules (this means that the repository will use other repositories as submodules) and the other ones just keeps everything together as if its 1 repo.

```
Repository A
- folder A (this is a submodule)
- folder B (this is a submodule)
- folder C (this is a submodule)

Repsitory B
- folder A
- folder B
- folder C
```

Both repositories contain the exact same files and folders. The only difference is that one of them contains submodules whereas the other does not.

Is this even possible to do and if so - how can I achieve this ?

Comment: One remote can not handle all submodules. You will need as many remotes as submodules + 1 main repository. To me sounds that you describe what `repo` does (it is heavily used in Android development).

Comment: @0andriy maybe i didnt explain it well. The one repository that mainains the submodules is one the uses submodules, such as adding a submodule to that repository.